# macos CLLocationManager Promt

Tags: swift, macos, core-location, cllocationmanager

I want to send location details when a push notification receives from server. But macos application doesn't ask location permission in launching. Added all privacy items in info.plist. It ask for permission when it calls locationmanager.startUpdatingLocation().And didn't ask again if i cancel it.The code is given below.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
  }
 func scanLocationRequest{
   locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
   // Call this when a notification receives.
 }
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let currentLocation = locations.last
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    sendLocationReport(currentLocation: currentLocation!)
 }

}
```

Comment: Is your app added to the Privacy pane in Systems Prefs? What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if user have location access or not use following code:

```
var isPermissionAvailable: Bool {
    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    switch status {
    case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
        return true
    case .denied, .restricted, .notDetermined:
        requestForLocation()
        return false
    }
}

func requestForLocation() {

    // Edit
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

To show pop-up at App launch, you can use following code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification:)` in `AppDelegate` class:

```
if isPermissionAvailable {
    // Do your work on permission available
}
```